# Flicker in translate animation

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I am translating one view from top to bottom and getting flicker on animation end have tried many solution but didn't work from me
like
1. starting small animation at the end.

```
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                    gallarylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                                    //gallarylayout.clearAnimation();
                                    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f,
                                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                                    animation.setDuration(1);

                                    imageSwitcherlayout
                                            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    bolgDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    gallarylayout.startAnimation(animation);
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = 
                                            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)                          
                                      gallarylayout.getLayoutParams();
                                            layoutParams1.leftMargin = 0;       
                                            layoutParams1.topMargin = 0;
                                            gallarylayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                                    // imageSwitcherlayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                                }
                            });
```

2.calling clear animation at the end.

```
gallarylayout.clearAnimation();
```

My code is...

```
slider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (conuter % 2 == 0) {
                    toTranslate = imageSwitcherlayout.getHeight();
                    TranslateAnimation transAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                            0, 0, gallarylayout.getPivotY(), toTranslate);

                    transAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                    //transAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                    Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            getActivity(), R.anim.up);
                    gallarylayout.startAnimation(transAnimation);
                    // Log.e("gallarylayout.getY()", gallarylayout.getY() + "");

                    //slideUp.setFillAfter(true);
                    transAnimation
                            .setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                    gallarylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(
                                        Animation animation) {
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                    gallarylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                                    //gallarylayout.clearAnimation();
                                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            240 + imageSwitcherlayout
                                                    .getHeight());
                                    viewPager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                                    imageSwitcherlayout
                                            .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    bolgDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f,
                                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                                    animation.setDuration(1);
                                    gallarylayout.startAnimation(animation);
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = 
                                            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gallarylayout.getLayoutParams();
                                            layoutParams1.leftMargin = 0;       
                                            layoutParams1.topMargin = 0;
                                            gallarylayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                                }
                            });
                    conuter++;
                } else {

                    Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            getActivity(), R.anim.down);
                    TranslateAnimation transAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                            0, 0, 0, -toTranslate - 10);

                    transAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                    //transAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
                    gallarylayout.startAnimation(transAnimation);

                    slide.setFillAfter(true);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (240));
                    viewPager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    transAnimation
                            .setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                    gallarylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(
                                        Animation animation) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                    gallarylayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                                    //gallarylayout.clearAnimation();
                                    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f,
                                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                                    animation.setDuration(1);

                                    imageSwitcherlayout
                                            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    bolgDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    gallarylayout.startAnimation(animation);
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = 
                                            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gallarylayout.getLayoutParams();
                                            layoutParams1.leftMargin = 0;       
                                            layoutParams1.topMargin = 0;
                                            gallarylayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                                    // imageSwitcherlayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

                                }
                            });
                    conuter++;
                }
            }
        });
```

where i am lacking what would be the solution in this case?

Comment: you pass four zeroes to TranslateAnimation,  it makes no sense

Comment: it make sense it is a trick to stop flicker when actual animation ends ....starting other small animation could stop the flicker i have  done this many of my solution to get rid of it but now its not working for me

Comment: if you use tricky code you ger tricky results,  this is not the path you should follow

Comment: ok then tell me what path should i follow you give me the solution..

Comment: make the minimalistic test code that doesn't work for you so other could run it and test it,  pasting the part of your project doesn't help much to understand your problem